Examples of homogeneous ideals with $J \cap B_+ \subset \sqrt{I}$ but $J \not\subset \sqrt{I}$.
This is a question about a Lemma in Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves.
The result states the following (this is Lemma 2.3.35, paraphrased to focus only on the part I am asking about):

Let $I, J$ be homogeneous ideals of a graded ring $B$. Then $V_+(I) \subset V_+(J)$ if and only if $J \cap B_+ \subset \sqrt{I}$.

I understand the proof, but I would like to have a deeper understanding of the appearance and implications of $B_+$ in the $\operatorname{Proj}$ construction, so I am wondering if someone can give an example for the necessity of taking $J \cap B_+$, rather than just $J$ (as happens in the affine case).
In other words, can someone provide an example of two homogeneous ideals $I, J$ of a graded ring $B$, with $J \cap B_+ \subset \sqrt{I}$, but $J \not\subset \sqrt{I}$?
Even better if you can give some intuition as to way we should "expect" that $B_+$ would show up in this Lemma.

This can’t happen if $J \subseteq B_+$, in particular if $J$ is generated by elements of positive degree. So for examples to occur, $B_0$ must not be a field. That explains why this doesn’t happen with the usual basic examples.
If $f \in B_0$ is a non-unit non-nilpotent element, then take $J = (f)$ and $I = J \cap B_+$. Then $f \notin \sqrt I$.

I guess you also need $f$ to be non-nilpotent.

Oops, you’re right.
